# How to create CustomCell programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have two arrays

1)nameArray;
2)numberArray;

These arrays contains names and numbers , I want to display these name and numbers in a tableview without using nib . How to create custom cell  programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"CellIdentifier";
CustomCellName *cell = (CustomCellName *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if(!cell) {
cell = [[CustomCellName alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reusableIdentifier:identifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.subtextLabel.text = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

The above code isn't tested, I'm not on a computer to do this (rather on my iPhone typing this all out) but it should be pretty much what you need code wise.

textLabel = property name you set for the label in your custom cell class
subtextLabel = property name you set for the label in your custom cell class

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file that should be sub-class of UITableViewCell. Here you can write your can create 2 labels you can display where ever you want.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *theID = @"TableViewCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theID];

return cell;
}
```

Here the CustomCell is subclass of UITableViewCell